# Adding code block into introduction

Tags: support, status-bydesign, documentation, documentation-editor

Trying to add the introduction below fails with this error message (and only when Submit for Review is hit):

> Introduction must be simple markdown - no images, tables, lists, etc.

Without the example intro topic gets removed, because topic specific focus is unclear for reviewers.

The desired content of intro section:

---

Different ways to create subcommands like in `hg` or `svn` with the exact command line interface and help output shown in the help message:

```
usage: sub <command>

commands:

 status -  show status
 list   -  print list
```

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1382/parsing-command-line-arguments covers broader topic of arguments parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introductions are severely limited because are intended to be quick signposts of what the topic is about. It's directly analogous to [tag wiki excerpts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts). If you feel the need to add code, it's a good indication you are really writing an example, syntax, parameters or even a remark. While it hasn't yet been implemented, introductions could be used as a short summary in a list of topics as tag excerpts are on a [list of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).

If you feel that a topic should prominently start with a bit of code, it's better to not include an introduction and put the code in a pinned example instead. Not every topic needs an introduction and starting off with a codeblock is very much in keeping with [guiding vision of Documentation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/21/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/).

Comment: I didn't know about pinned examples.